# Click listener for button doesn't work in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I want to run some JavaScript code before modal window is shown, but when i click on button nothing happens and browser console doesn't give me any error.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv3ebxa8/)

```
    <a href="#addEdgeModalB" class="btn"> EDGE </a>

<div id="addEdgeModal" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal">    
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>


<script>
       $("#addEdgeModalB").on("click",function(e){
           alert("click");
           $("addEdgeModal").modal("show"); 
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$("[href='#addEdgeModalB']").on("click",function(e){
   alert("click");           
});
```

There is no id there for using `id selector` here. Use `attribute equals selector` at this context.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv3ebxa8/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [**this**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) for the correct `modal` markup.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/Lv3ebxa8/8/)

```
$("a.btn").on("click",function(e){
    alert("click");

});
```